# R Select files in working directory based on criteria in CSV

Tags: r, select, conditional-statements

I have a working directory called "NVSPL" of over 7,000 .txt files. Some of those files I want to ignore during my analyses. I've created a separate CSV file with a column that contains the name and extension of each of the over 7,000 .txt files in my working directory. The second column in the CSV has either a "0" if I want to keep the associated .txt file or a "1" if I want to ignore the associated .txt file.

How can I have R go through the CSV, find all of the "0"s and create a new folder with the associated .txt files?

[image]

In this case, I would want a new folder that would only include files with "0"s in the "GoodData" column.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to create a new folder and move files around if you have flagged the files? Just use the flag as the basis for reading into R or not.

Comment: @neilfws thank you for the comment. I agree, that would be the better way to go about this to minimize the creation of new folders. Do you have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `file.copy`.  Subset the files from the 'FileName' column and then with `file.copy` copy those files into a new directory created

```
files <- file.path("path/to", with(df1, FileName[!GoodData]))
dir.create("path/to/NVSPL_new", recursive = TRUE)


for(file in files) {

   file.copy(file, "path/to/NVSPL_new")
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I'm not sure I see how this works. I'm assuming "df1" is the csv file already loaded into R. Assuming that and adding the path to the .txt files directory where you have "path/to", R returns an error saying:

 "Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'FileName' not found"

Any ideas? Also, I don't see how your code selects based on "0" or "1".

Thank you!

Comment: @user3494534 Yes, your 'FileName' column have only the file name and not the path.  It needs the correct path to copy the files.  I used `path/to/` so that you can change those by using either `paste` or `file.path`

Comment: @user3494534 Regarding the `!GoodData`, the column is binary.  If we negate (`!`), then it is converted to logical with 0 changed to TRUE and 1 to FALSE.  So, we use that to subset the FileName',  It can also be done explicitly as `FileName[GoodData == 0]`

Comment: @user3494534 Do you need double `\\`